# Fastlane Match fails to verify certificates and profiles

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm trying to run `fastlane match appstore`. It successfully decrypts the cert repo, says it successfully logs in to Apple Dev Portal, generates a cert and installs it.

But it always fails at "Verifying certificates..." like this:

```
[13:48:03]: Starting login with user 'xxx@yyyy.com'
[13:48:05]: Successfully logged in
[13:48:05]: Fetching profiles...
[13:48:05]: Verifying certificates...
[13:48:05]: No existing profiles found, that match the certificates you have installed locally! Creating a new provisioning profile for you
[13:48:06]: Creating new provisioning profile for 'xxx.yyy.Reign' with name 'match AppStore aaa.bbb.ccc' for 'ios' platform
[13:48:07]: An error occurred while verifying your certificates and profiles with the Apple Developer Portal.
[13:48:07]: If you already have your certificates stored in git, you can run `fastlane match` in readonly mode
[13:48:07]: to just install the certificates and profiles without accessing the Dev Portal.
[13:48:07]: To do so, just pass `readonly: true` to your match call.

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

Traceback (most recent call last):
    26: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
    25: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    24: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:111:in `take_off'
    22: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/commands_generator.rb:25:in `start'
    21: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/commands_generator.rb:187:in `run'
    20: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    19: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in `run!'
    18: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    17: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    16: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    15: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/commands_generator.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in run'
    14: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:107:in `run'
    13: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:107:in `each'
    12: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:108:in `block in run'
    11: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:108:in `loop'
    10: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:109:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     9: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/runner.rb:262:in `fetch_provisioning_profile'
     8: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/match/lib/match/generator.rb:103:in `generate_provisioning_profile'
     7: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/sigh/lib/sigh/manager.rb:8:in `start'
     6: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/sigh/lib/sigh/runner.rb:42:in `run'
     5: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/sigh/lib/sigh/runner.rb:170:in `create_profile!'
     4: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/models/profile.rb:73:in `create'
     3: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/provisioning/provisioning.rb:79:in `post_profiles'
     2: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/provisioning/client.rb:46:in `post'
     1: from /Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/provisioning/client.rb:82:in `proxy_post'
/Users/nicholasstamas/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.155.1/spaceship/lib/spaceship/connect_api/client.rb:158:in `handle_response': [!] { (Spaceship::UnexpectedResponse)
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "d4e4b07a-8083-4369-94a3-c1b655eb83ea",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.NOT_ALLOWED",
    "title" : "A relationship in the provided entity is not allowed for this request",
    "detail" : "No devices can be associated to Provisioning Profiles for the App Store."
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error today. Seems like possibly an API change at Apple?

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue. This is the first time I'm setting up fastlane and I am getting this error!

Answer (score 2):

Seems this was fixed in 2.155.3.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.155.3

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by register a new iPhone device to the developer account.
The easiest way would be to connect your iPhone to your computer and then inside xcode at the top bar, select the iPhone connected (as if you were to run the app with that device instead of a Simulator), then in the Signing & Capabilities tab, you get the option to register the device.

I think you can also register a device in the developer.apple.com site if you have the UUID of the device.